# Power (monomial) form conversion to Chebyshev form

Tags: polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Given a polynomial in the monomial form e.g. like $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + a_n x^n$, how is it possible to convert it to the Chebyshev basis (i.e. represent it as a linear combination of Chebyshev polynomials)?

Such representation exists for any polynomial of the form $p(x)$ (see above), but I can't find the formulas (after 2> hours of googling)..

I think the question is valuable, although it's naive and very straightforward, since I found no open source of information about this (and the representation of Chebyshev polynomials as sums of monomials can be found everywhere...)

Comment: Maybe the [orthogonality of Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) will help, at least when you allow to do numerical integration.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630456/chebyshev-coefficients-from-a-polynomial?rq=1 contains the answer.. This question may be closed/deleted, however it is sad that it was hard to find the older question (may be because of the non-representative keywords and question title)...